# capturing data stream using Apple's External Accessories API

Tags: objective-c, ios, iostream

Hi I am making an application for iPAD wherein I have to capture the data coming from an external device which sends 512 values per second. I used Apple's External Accessories API for the same and have the code as below:-

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream*)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent  
{  
    switch (streamEvent)  
 {  
   case NSStreamEventNone:  //Sent when open complete
  //NSLog(@"NSStreamEventNone");
   break;   
  case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:  //Sent when open complete

  //NSLog(@"NStreamEventOpenCompleted: %@", theStream);
  break ;

  case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    {
   //NSLog(@"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable");

    uint8_t buffer[1024];
    unsigned int len=0;

    len=[(NSInputStream *)theStream  read:buffer maxLength:1024];
    if(len>0){      

    NSData* data=[NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:len];

    NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataencoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

   }
    }
 break;   

 case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:  
    os = theStream;
    break;
 case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:  
   //NSLog(@"NSStreamEventErrorOccurred");
    break;   

  case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:  
    ////NSLog(@"NSStreamEventEndEncountered");
    break;   
  default:  
    break;  
  }  
 }
```

What I get from this is some garbled text without proper encoding. I have tried using the below too:-

```
 NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataencoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but this just keeps returning null.
Edit:- when I NSLog, I get the below:-

```
 v¬™¬™¬Ä√ø√π¬Ö¬™¬™¬Ä √ø√ª¬É¬™¬™¬Ä√øK3¬™¬™¬Ä√ø¬£√õ¬™¬™¬Ä√ø√ã¬≥¬™¬™¬Ä√ø}¬™¬™¬Ä√ø√•¬ô¬™¬™¬Ä
```

I am supposed to get integers here. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you NSLog the "dataencoding"? Are you getting data?

Comment: Please see the NSLog of the returned value above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your NSLog appears to be a string of extended ASCII characters.  Assuming they are from the Apple extended Ascii character set then the uint8_t (1 byte) data represented by the start of the snippet you listed is:

¬Ä√ø√π¬Ö¬™¬™¬Ä...

Represented as decimal this is:

172, 196, 26, 248, 26, 192, 172, 214, 172, 34, 172 ...

Is this your data?  Here is some code to test the output.

```
NSString *receivedString = @"¬Ä√ø√π¬Ö¬™¬™¬Ä"; // Change this to the string variable you were using with NSLog

for (int i=0; i<[receivedString length]; i++) 
{
    unsigned char asciiCode = [ receivedString characterAtIndex:i];
    NSLog( @"Value at %d is %d", i, asciiCode ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you receive are raw values. Most definitely they are not UTF8 characters. Most likely you'll have to put each 2 bytes into a 2-byte integer directly from the NSData's bytes.